# Integration Test with Spring: Cannot convert value of type error

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am in the process of developing Integration Test scripts for our spring application.  When I run the test from ant I am getting the following error message: Any ideal as why?

Testcase:

```
testgetDefaultItemForStoreWithInvalidStoreId(com.xyz.business.admin.role.RoleUtilityUnitTest):  
Caused an ERROR Error creating bean with name 'groundingService' defined in URL 
[file:/C:/workspace/_EACE1_0_06/EB_Ace_Vob/Business/build/classess/businessContext.xml]: Error 
setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested 
PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are: PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: 
Failed to convert property value of type [$Proxy47] to required type 
[com.xyz.business.grounding.service.OdometerPdfStatement] for property 'odometerPdfStatement'; nested exception 
is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy47] to required type 
[com.xyz.business.grounding.service.OdometerPdfStatement] for property 'odometerPdfStatement': no matching editors or 
conversion strategy found org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with 
name 'groundingService' defined in 
URL [file:/C:/workspace/_EACE1_0_06/EB_Ace_Vob/Business/build/classess/businessContext.xml]: Error 
setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested 
PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are: PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: 
Failed to convert property value of type [$Proxy47] to required type 
[com.xyz.business.grounding.service.OdometerPdfStatement] for property 'odometerPdfStatement'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy47] to 
required type [com.xyz.business.grounding.service.OdometerPdfStatement] for property 'odometerPdfStatement': 
no matching editors or conversion strategy found Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessException details (1) are: 
PropertyAccessException 1:
```

OdometerPDFStatement is a class (not an interface)

I have the following:

```
    <bean id="odometerPdfStatement" class="com.xyz.business.grounding.service.OdometerPdfStatement"/>


<bean id="groundingService" class="com.xyz.business.grounding.service.GroundingServiceImpl">
    <property name="groundingInformationManager" ref="groundingInformationManager"/>
    <property name="codeManager" ref="codeManager"/>
    <property name="userManager" ref="userManager"/>
    <property name="configurator" ref="groundingConfigurator"/>
    <property name="velocityPropertyFilePath" value="velocity.properties"/>
    <property name="velocityTemplate" value="OdometerStatement.vm"/>
    <property name="odometerStatementXSLResourceFile" value="classpath:OdometerStatement2xsl-fo.xsl"/>
    <property name="imagePropertyFile" value="classpath:images.properties"/>
    <property name="odometerPdfStatement" ref="odometerPdfStatement"/>
    <property name="inspectionInformationManager" ref="inspectionInformationManager"/>
    <property name="saleEventManager" ref="saleEventManager"/>
    <property name="vehicleHistoryManager" ref="vehicleHistoryManager"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: are you using some sort of AOP anywhere? "$Proxy47" sounds suspicious

Comment: boyd4715:  yes we do have AOP - does that make a difference in how to run unit/int testing from ant?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this a few times. It means that the proxy that spring created does not implement the correct inteface.

I suggest you put a break point on the injector and inspect that $Proxy47 to ascertain what it is implementing.

Also if that class om.xyz.business.grounding.service.OdometerPdfStatement implements 2 interfaces I'm not sure how spring decides which one to use when proxying. I suspect it might implement two interfaces and the proxy is being created on the other one.

Comment: We are using Spring 2.0.x with JUnit 4.6 any know issues with that?  Should I drop it to JUnit 3.8?

Comment: Also, the integration testing I am doing is a backend application - Ear with EJB -

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Just bumped into the same problem; dropping interfaces helped.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add the cglib jar to your classpath. Cglib insures that Spring can proxy concrete classes, not just interfaces.

Comment: I have the following in my class path:  cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar.  Note that I am able to run my test script in the IDE with no issues.  Using RAD 7.0.X as the IDE.

Comment: Actually, `[$Proxy47]` shows that cglib is available and in action; it's just it got it wrong what exactly is being proxied.

Comment: @alf that class name indicates that a classic Java proxy is used ; cglib proxied classes will include EnhancedByCGLIB ( http://osdir.com/ml/java.cglib.devel/2005-06/msg00025.html )

Comment: In other words, Spring saw the interface being implemented and decided that classic Java proxy will fit just fine? Oh joy.

Comment: @alf - no , Spring proxied only the interfaces since CGLib was not available.

Comment: I can prove I had exactly the same problem, and solved it by removing interfaces; no dependencies were changed, cglib was in the classpath all the way. See also the answer above.